# weird shell script error: invalid option return: usage: return [n]

Tags: command-line, scripts, debugging

This programme checks if a certain book title exist by matching user input of book title and book author.

```
function removebook_option()
{
    echo -n "Title : "
    read title_input2

    echo -n "Author: "
    read author_input2

    checkexist $title_input2 $author_input2
    error=$?
    echo "$error"

    if [ $error != -1 ];then
        #removebook
            echo "New book title $title_input removed successfully"
        else
        echo "Book does not exist"


    fi 

}

function checkexist()
{  
   counter=0

   for x in ${title[@]} 
   do

    for y in ${author[@]} 
    do
        if [  $x == $1 ] && [ $y == $2 ];
        then
            error=$counter 
                return "$error"
        fi
    done
    counter=$((counter+1))
   done

   error=-1
   return "$error"

}

title=(foo1 foo2)
author=(bar1 bar2)
removebook_option
```

I am getting a very weird error , where `function checkexist()` returns 2 instead of -1 when there isnt a match which happens when returning value `error=-1`

> line 43: return: -1: invalid option return: usage: return [n]

**EDIT : For reasons unknown , i can only return values from 0-255 , does anyone know how to return negative values??**

You can try to input incorrect data to see the weird error

**I need help resolving this issue thanks!!!!**

Comment: What is `checkexist()` meant to return if a book is found? Currently, it is returning the index of the title (I believe)

Comment: @minerz029 that is correct

Comment: Apparently its because i can only return values between 0 and 255 , i cant return negative values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error:

```
line 43: return: -1: invalid option return: usage: return [n]
```

This is because the `-1` is interpreted as an option. Use this, `--` means 'end of options':

```
return -- -1
```

which returns with `255`.

---

Working solution:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function removebook_option()
{
    echo -n "Title : "
    read title_input2

    echo -n "Author: "
    read author_input2

    error="$(checkexist "$title_input2" "$author_input2")" # <--
    echo "$error"

    if [[ "$error" != NOT_FOUND ]]; then # <--
        #removebook
        echo "New book title $title_input removed successfully"
    else
        echo "Book does not exist"
    fi 

}

function checkexist()
{  
   counter=0

   for x in "${title[@]}" # <--
   do
        for y in "${author[@]}" # <--
        do
            if [[  $x == $1 ]] && [[ $y == $2 ]]; # <--
            then
                error=$counter 
                echo "$error" # <--
                return
            fi
        done
        ((counter++)) # <--
   done

   error=NOT_FOUND # <--
   echo "$error"
   return
}

title=(foo1 foo2)
author=(bar1 bar2)
removebook_option
```

Edits marked with  `# <--`

This works by instead of returning an integer value, it echoes it (writes to screen). Usually, this would print to the terminal however the `$( ... )` syntax captures the printed output, and assigns it to `error` in `removebook_option()`. This allows 'returning' any string, I've made it return a sentinel value of `NOT_FOUND` if not found.

Notes:

- Array expansion should be wrapped with double quotes: `"${author[@]}"` and `"${title[@]}"`
- Use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`.

Comment: Actually i get another error/warning : numeric argument required , how to resolve this??

Comment: @Computernerd In that case, just replace all `return` in `checkexist()` with `return 0`. Also, ensure `/bin/bash` is being used, it works for me.